# Understanding ANR stack trace given by google play

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-trace, google-play-console, android-anr-dialog

We recently developed a game using cocos2d-js (3.17.1) for android & getting more number of ANR's,I want to understand how we can easily understand the stack trace reported.

I observed like some of the lines are bold & some of them are light gray why is that, each thread have some state, & some ANR's have warnings in yellow, but not getting which thread caused the problem.

Searched on google, gone through lot of posts,google play android docs, its just gives a information about what is mean of ANR, (main thread got blocked) and how to handle / prevent from ANR's, doesn't exactly get how can I extract meaning from stack trace, how to go through stack trace, which thread exactly caused the problem.

**Full stack trace is here** https://del.dog/unafalycej.txt

Attaching a screenshot of ANR which we got most number of time (main thread & blockes thread).

[ANR title screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqpX6.png)

[main thread screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqpX6.png)

[blocked thread screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqpX6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my experience ANRs are the most difficult to analyze, but below mentioned are some possible steps that I do RCA.

1. Keep looking for a specific action after which you see the ANR, look for its API/method/`onClick`, try analyzing that code.
2. Look at the logs for these specific method, are there any unnecessary calls in between, try profiling if possible.
3. After a application experiences a ANR, android stores a at `/data/anr/traces.txt`. Try pulling this file and start analyzing it. Look for main thread, check its `STATE` and stacktrace. Refer [this](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-read-dalvik-sigquit-output.html) for details on traces file.
4. Trying identifying threads with large jiffies. See their call stack as well.
5. There also thread dump and `systrace` like feature which can be useful.